# NoSuchJobException: No job configuration with the name [] was registered

Tags: java, spring-batch

I'm a complete beginner when it comes to Spring-Batch and need to fix this bug. Spring Batch mostly works as expected at the moment but when I try to stop a job with `SimpleJobOperator.stop(long executionId)`

**What I'm doing:**
I want to stop a job that was started earlier and is still running.

This screenshot shows the method `stop()` of class `SimpleJobOperator` provided by Spring-Batch.
The exception is thrown because the job name can't be found in the `jobRegistry` on line 388.

I think the `JobRegistry` bean is not properly configured, therefore the `AutomaticJobRegistrar` can't put the job name into the `JobRegistry` earlier.

[image: SimpleJobOperator.stop()]

This is an excerpt from the configuration class. I didn't found any @Bean for the `JobRegistry`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@ComponentScan
@EnableConfigurationProperties(BatchWorkerProperties.class)
public class BatchProcessingConfig {

    public static final String BATCHEXECUTOR = "BatchExecutor";

    @Bean(BATCHEXECUTOR)
    public TaskExecutor batchExecutor(final BatchWorkerProperties workerProperties) {
          ...

    }

    @Bean
    public JobLauncher jobLauncher(@Qualifier(BATCHEXECUTOR) final TaskExecutor taskExecutor, final JobRepository jobRepository) {
        final SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();

        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
        return jobLauncher;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor(JobRegistry jobRegistry) {
        final JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor = new JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor();
        jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
        return jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor;
    }

}
```

**Actual Result:**

```
org.springframework.batch.core.launch.NoSuchJobException: No job configuration with the name [ingest-pipeline-job] was registered
        at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry.getJob(MapJobRegistry.java:68) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy128.getJob(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator.stop(SimpleJobOperator.java:388) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$44ee6049.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f45d65d3.stop(<generated>) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at
```

And I found this INFO in the logs at startup. So I guess something is wrong with the @Autowired beans

```
2021-06-11 17:08:56.983  INFO 217737 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'jobRegistry' of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy128] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
```

**Expected Result:**
Stop method returns without any exceptions.

EDIT 16.06.2021

This are the first lines of the service class `BatchJobService` where amongst other things the JobOperator is initialized by constructor injection.

```
@Service
public class BatchJobService {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BatchJobService.class);

    public static final String JOB_LAUNCHER = "batchServiceJobLauncher";

    private final JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    private final JobExplorer jobExplorer;

    private final JobOperator jobOperator;

    private final CrashedJobKiller crashedJobKiller;

    private final Map<String, Job> batchJobs;

    /**
     * Instantiates a new batch job service.
     *
     * @param jobLauncher the job launcher
     * @param batchJobs the batch jobs
     * @param jobExplorer the job explorer
     * @param jobOperator the job operator
     * @param jobRegistry the job registry
     * @param crashedJobKiller the crashed job killer
     */
    @Autowired
    public BatchJobService(
        @Qualifier(JOB_LAUNCHER) final JobLauncher jobLauncher, // do we need a qualifier here?
        final List<Job> batchJobs,
        final JobExplorer jobExplorer,
        final JobOperator jobOperator, final JobRegistry jobRegistry, final CrashedJobKiller crashedJobKiller) {
        this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;
        this.jobExplorer = jobExplorer;
        this.jobOperator = jobOperator;
        this.crashedJobKiller = crashedJobKiller;

        this.batchJobs = batchJobs.stream().collect(toMap(Job::getName, Function.identity()));

    }
```

Comment: Can you share your `SimpleJobOperator` bean definition? `@EnableBatchProcessing` creates a `JobRegistry` bean, but you should manually set it on your `JobOperator`.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine good question, there is no JobOperator bean definition. I will look into that now. Do you maybe have an example of that?

Comment: `when I try to stop a job with SimpleJobOperator.stop(long executionId)`: my question is about the instance of `SimpleJobOperator` you use to stop the job: if it is not defined as a bean, that's ok, but in that case, you need to set the job registry created by `@EnableBatchProcessing` on it.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Understood, but how do I set the `JobRegistry` of a `SimpleJobOperator`?

Comment: How did you create that instance of `SimpleJobOperator` that you used to stop the job? There is a setter on it for the job registry.  Please share more details about your batch configuration to be able to help you in an efficient way.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I added parts of the service class where the `SimpleJobOperator` is autowired in the constructor

Comment: Thanks for the update, but this does not show where the `SimpleJobOperator` is defined/created. This beans is not created by `@EnableBatchProcessing`, so it should be defined in some class (I see you use `@ComponentScan`) that is not shared in your question. You need to make sure that the job registry is set on that instance of `SimpleJobOperator`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233838/discussion-between-martin-and-mahmoud-ben-hassine).

Answer (score 0):

To stop a job programmatically you need to track your jobs by registering through the `JobRegistry`. When 'spring-batch' is activated, for example by `@EnableBatchProcessing` an instance of `JobRegistry` is registered into the IoC and it's available for dependency injection; so you could "`@Autowired`" when you need.

To register a job you could:

1. Use `JobRegistry#register` explicitly to add your jobs manually
2. Register a `JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor` into the IoC. The processor is going to automatically register all the Job available from the IoC. This means all the bean and components which a registered into Spring IoC are added by default. Example:

```
// First register into IoC the JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor
// Do not forget to set its registry with the SpringBatch jobRegistry instance
@Bean 
public JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor(JobRegistry jobRegistry) {
     final JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor answer = new JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor();
     answer.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
     return answer;
    }
```

```
@Bean // This one is registered
public Job helloWorldJob() {
      return jobFactory.get("helloWorld")
             ...
             .build();
}
```

```
@Component // This one is registered automatically
public class HelloWorldJob implements Job {
 ...
}
```

```
public void runHelloWorldJob() {
// this one is not registered automatically because is not registered into IoC. 
// You need to explicitly add it manually
 Job hello = jobFactory.get("helloWorld")
             ...
             .build();
 jobLauncher.run(hello, ...); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually you can use @Autowired JobRegistry and then your "jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor" will look something like this:

```
   @Autowired
   JobRegistry jr;

   @Bean
   public JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor() {
   JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor postProcessor = new JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor();
   postProcessor.setJobRegistry(jr);
   return postProcessor;
```

}

Comment: Still the same issue. I'm going to look deeper into the AutomaticJobRegistrar.

Comment: @Martin have you found the solution yet?

Comment: @Eatsamulhaq Sorry I did not. I expect the spring batch configuration of this project to be broken.